# Initializing 2d matrix with elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I want to write a really simple function that creates a matrix of specific size, with a function that allows me to initialize the elements in the matrix. Simple stuff, but I wanted to try a few more C++11 features at the same time.

```
template<class T, class Generator>
vector<vector<T> > create_matrix(int nr_rows, int nr_cols, Generator& gen) {
    vector<vector<T> > matrix(nr_rows, vector<T>(nr_cols));
    for (auto& row : matrix) {
        generate_n(row.begin(), row.end(), gen);
    }
    return matrix;
}

// calling code
mt19937 engine;
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9);
vector<vector<int> > matrix_a = create_matrix<int>(3, 4, [&]() {
    return dist(engine);
});
```

The compilation fails with

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\algorithm(1562): error : no operator "+" matches these operands
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\algorithm(1532): error : no operator "<" matches these operands
```

under Visual Studio 2012 (the CUDA SDK doesn't have official support for VS2013 so that's no option). So what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake - `generate_n` does take a size parameter as the second argument not an iterator. Why the hell the error messages must be completely useless is beyond me, but then it's c++ - what else do I expect?

Comment: It's not really C++'s fault that visual studio fails to indicate that the actual error is that template instantiation fails.

Comment: @Cubic g++ for the same problem returns an error message of 113 unhelpful lines. clang's `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('decltype(__n + 0)' (aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >') and 'int')` isn't that much better either (the 47 other lines don't help either). So yes I think it is fair to fault C++ for a design that makes it almost impossible to give good error messages for simple errors.